# SQLlite - no such column in a DELETE command

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public void addFavourite(User user,Winkel winkel){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME,winkel.getNaam());
    values.put(COLUMN_POSTCODE, winkel.getPostcode());
    values.put(COLUMN_DEELGEMEENTE, winkel.getDeelGemeente());
    values.put(COLUMN_GEMEENTE, winkel.getGemeente());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADRES, winkel.getAdres());
    Log.d("lol",user.getUserName()); // Log is succesfull
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.getUserName());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_FAVOURITES, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public void deleteFavourite(User user,Winkel winkel){

    String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME+"=" + user.getUserName() + " AND " + COLUMN_NAME + "=" + winkel.getNaam();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(selectQuery);
    db.close();
}


    String CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_FAVOURITES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_POSTCODE + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_DEELGEMEENTE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_GEMEENTE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_ADRES + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_USERNAME+ ") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_USERS + "(username) " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVOURITES_TABLE);
```

Sql exception when trying to delete favourite:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Gebruikersnaam (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM favorieten WHERE username=Gebruikersnaam AND naam=EUROCITY
```

Note: so I'm assuming either something is wrong when adding the favourite, and the username actually doesn't get added to the table, or theres something wrong in my create table statement, or theres something wrong in my deletequery. I can't figure out what though. Why isn't this working?

Comment: You need to enclose your strings in single quotes. I.e.: `WHERE username='Gebruikersnaam' AND naam='EUROCITY'`

Comment: You forgot the quotes arond your values. But actually you should use Prepared Statements

Comment: @juergend Yes, bound parameters work better. They also take care of doubling the single quotes in case of a string which contains one or more apostrophes (`'` => `''`)

Comment: @Rotwang What do you mean by that? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Reload the page and see the updated comment. That's not only for SQLite. EVERY SQL based RDBMS will require that "framing"

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks. How would I use preparedstatement in this case? I still have a lot of similar code to write, so maybe it's better? It's working now, if you post your comment as answer I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your strings in single quotes.
I.e.: WHERE username='Gebruikersnaam' AND naam='EUROCITY'

Bound parameters will work better.
They also take care of doubling the single quotes in case of a string which contains one or more apostrophes (`"'"` => `"''"`).
So you don't have to manually replace them.

In your case, it's something like this:

```
// Put your parameters in this array (no matter if they are numeric types
// because the SQL statement is a string anyway),
// in the exact order of appearance in your query or SQL command
String[] strParams = new String[]{user.getUserName(), winkel.getNaam()};
// Your modified SQL command with the parameter placeholders (?)
String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + 
    " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ? AND " + COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
// Use this execSQL() syntax
db.execSQL(selectQuery, strParams);
db.close();
```